# Ext JS Progress Bar - text align to center

Tags: extjs

Just started using progressbarwidget, I want the text from my textTpl to be center aligned within the progress bar at all times regardless of what percentage the bar is at, when I mean centered I mean the center of the progress bar and not center of the progress value. See fiddle below and attached image

[image: progress bar currently and what I want!]

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dm7

I seen a reference on another thread to set position : relative, this does set the text to the center of the bar but doing so means the bar does not show the progress anymore. I see when the progress bar is created it has 2 divs, containing the following classes, x-progress-text and x-progress-bar, both contain the text value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?313019-Progress-Bar-how-to-center-Text-at-all-times-regardless-of-percentage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `ProgressBarWidget`, and override the `template`, like:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.ProgressBarWidget', {
    extend: 'Ext.ProgressBarWidget',

    xtype: 'fiddle-progressbarwidget',

    template: [{
        reference: 'backgroundEl'
    }, {
        reference: 'barEl'
    }, {
        reference: 'textEl',
        style: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0
        }
    }],
});
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dn4

Comment: hi, this looks very promising, one thing I did notice if you set the value to 0.1 (10%) the text is duplicated, one is centered and other is left aligned, I managed to sort this by adding the style properties to the backgroundEl as well.  I will plug  this into my application and update if it has resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The definitive solution is to add an `onResize` handler on the progress bar container:

```
onResize: function () {
    var me = this,
        progressBar = me.down('progressbarwidget');

    // Set text width to element width so that it can be centered
    progressBar.setWidth(progressBar.el.getWidth());
}
```

[image]

*This idea is copied from what happens in* `Ext.grid.column.Widget.onResize()`.

---

The solution from user **CD..** doesn't work (nor does the one in **user2751034** comment)
in the case you have two-color-text, like in *Classic* theme:

[image]

even if you reproduce the template in Sencha sources (with `textEl` children of `barEl`):

[image]